# Apply Numerical Filters in DataGridview in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have data gridview and in one colum contain numeric values and i am trying to apply filters like show greater and etc but I am not able to come with solution.

screen:

[image]

code:

calling the class method and assigning the value to datagridview

```
dataGridViewKeywords = filter.Filter(dataGridViewKeywords, mainValue, true);
```

Class File:

```
class FilterDataGridView
{
    private DataGridView modifiedDGV = new DataGridView();
    private string keyword;
    private int competionScore;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();


    public DataGridView Filter (DataGridView dgv, int value, bool isabove)
    {
        modifiedDGV.Columns.Add("keyword", "Keyword") ;
        modifiedDGV.Columns.Add("competition", "Avg. Competition Score");
        modifiedDGV.Columns.Add("moreinfo", "More Info");

        if (isabove)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < dgv.Rows.Count; row++)
            {
                competionScore = Convert.ToInt32(dgv.Rows[row].Cells[1].Value);
                keyword = dgv.Rows[row].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

                if (competionScore > value)
                    modifiedDGV.Rows.Add(keyword, competionScore, "View");
            }
        }

        return modifiedDGV;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest solution is to work with `BindingSource`.

You provide your data within a `BindingSource`-class and set the `DataGridView.DataSource` to this `BindingSource`.

`BindingSource` itself is more or less a better List and also has a `Filter`-property which lets you apply the criteria very easy. This way you don't have to mess around with all these items and even create a second `DataGridView`.

Comment: thanks for the reply but how do apply filter for int i am trying the filter does not seem to work `bind.Filter = "AvgCompetitionScore > 30";`

Comment: That's not exactly true. BindingSource does `not` implement filtering/sorting for you, it really is just a wrapper and relies on the underlying data source to do that. To be more concrete, to `IBindingListView` implementation. The only standard data source that really implements that interface is `System.Data.DataView`.

Comment: @IvanStoev now I understands I ll try figure out the solution now