# How To Apply BindingSource.Filter To Numeric Values (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, filter, bindingsource

I am trying to apply greater than filter for datagridview column using binding source but it's seems not working

here is the screen of gridview

[image]

here is code

```
BindingSource bind = new BindingSource();
        bind.DataSource = dataGridViewKeywords.DataSource;

        bind.Filter = "AvgCompetitionScore > 30";

        dataGridViewKeywords.DataSource = bind.DataSource;
```

Comment: You should Load your data and assign your data to `DataSource` property of `BindingSouce`, then when you need to filter data, Set `Filter` property to the filter that you need.

Comment: Are you using bound mode at all? Show us your code that populates the grid.

Comment: For more information about the expression syntax that you can use, see this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @RezaAghaei I think he's trying to follow the answer to his another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33046942/apply-numerical-filters-in-datagridview-in-c-sharp which is not quite correct. I've put comment there, but suspect that OP is using unbound mode.

Comment: @IvanStoev i ll try with the variation you suggested and this was a different question thats why I thought create different question rather than including it on previous one

Comment: @IvanStoev If the OP is using `DataTable` as data source and using data bound mode, he can use `BindingSource.Filter`

Comment: @RezaAghaei That's right, the question is does he :-)

Comment: @AlstonAntony You don't really need `BindingSource` for that, the easiest is to put your data to a `DataTable`, set it as data source to your grid, and then use your `DataTable.DefaultView` for filtering/sorting - like here [DataTable.DefaultView Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.defaultview(v=vs.110).aspx)